# C# Retrieve JSON Object by Containing Value

Tags: c#, json, .net

I've come across a bit of a problem. I want to convert a steam game name to its corresponding steam app id via the [steamapi](https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/). I'm trying to figure out how to get the entirety of a object from a value it contains (

```
{"applist":{"apps":[{"appid":230410,"name":"Warframe"}, {"appid":25300,"name":"Call of Duty"}, {"appid":292410,"name":"Team Fortress 2"}]}}
```

for example. the name here is Warframe. but I want to grab the entirety of this object just by the "name" value. I've been looking for an answer for awhile. any help would be appreciated

I tried deserializing the response to a class. but this seemed to be useless since all objects contain the same value name just with different titles

Comment: What is "entirety"? can you show the example what you want to retrive? I can see only one object, what else are going to find?

Comment: Have a look at `Array.Find()`, `List.Find()` and `Enumerable.First()` for examples of how to single value in a collection based on one of its properties

Comment: @Serge i hotlinked the json value to "steamapi" its a jumble of json containing every game on the steam store containing its name and appid

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson will do!

Comment: @willcodes I'm at work, and that link is blocked by my company's firewall. It's a good idea to include the link, but it's also good to include a bit more information directly in your post in case people can't access the link. In this case, I would include the parent object/array. You don't have to include all the child items, just two or three is enough to demonstrate

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I see. I have included a sized down version of the full json in the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
var result=JObject.Parse(json)["applist"]["apps"].Where(a=> (string)a["name"]=="Warframe").FirstOrDefault();

//if you need id

var appid = (int) result["appid"];

//or in one line

int appid = (int) JObject.Parse(json)["applist"]["apps"]
.FirstOrDefault(a=> (string)a["name"]=="Warframe")?["appid"];
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` can take the predicate directly, no need to add `Where` inbetween

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I  always like to separate flys from burgers.

Comment: @Serge I'm getting a System.ArgumentNullException when a game's name has a ":" in the name

Comment: @willcodes pls show the example where do you have an error

Comment: @Serge sorry for the delay! I fixed it, it was a issue with the full json response not being pulled not the code itself.